# Issues with C++ bitfields

Tags: c++, bit-fields

I have to write a file header with a specific data format. For simplicity, let's just assume it is:

- bits [0-7]: index a
- bits [8-9]: index b
- bits [10-15]: index c

All of them are simple unsigned integers. I thought I might use bit fields to get a nice syntax. I defined

```
struct Foo {
  unsigned int a : 8, b : 2, c : 6;
};
```

However, I get `sizeof(Foo) == 4`. Why is that so? I expected a 2-byte structure here. Is the compiler adding padding between my fields? If I use `unsigned char` as my member type, I get a size of 2 bytes.

On [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field), it says:

> Multiple adjacent bit fields are usually packed together (although
> this behavior is implementation-defined).

Does that mean that I cannot rely on the fields being packed together? Eventually, I will use `memcpy` to turn this `struct` into a stream of bytes and write that to a file. Is that not a good use of bit fields? This will only work if these bits are guaranteed to be packed together.

EDIT: The actual header relates to the [GIF format](http://giflib.sourceforge.net/whatsinagif/bits_and_bytes.html). Many indexes are packed into just a few bytes. Some of them are made up of 1, 2, 3 or more bits.

Comment: I bet `sizeof(unsigned int) == 4` on your platform. Your type's size won't be smaller than the member type. If you remove your bitfields you will probably get a `sizeof(Foo) == 12;`. The bitfields are probably working as intended here.

Comment: If you intended to perform memory representation streaming, you should consider using fixed width types like `std::uint32_t` or `std::uint64_t` from [`#include <cstdint>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdint) to avoid portability problems.

Comment: [uint16_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) look at these types if you want a specific size

Comment: Please be more specific. Please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with sample input and expected output. From the question I got the feeling that simple bit shifts should do the job

Comment: I am not sure I understand what bit fields bring to the table then. I thought I would be trading away some performance for complete control over my memory layout. It would have only been worth it if my total struct size was more than 4 bytes then?

Comment: @Touloudou If you had no bitfields, your `struct` would be 3 times larger. Here, it packs all 3 members into a single member's representation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux true enough, but I care more about the layout than I do about the footprint here.

Comment: @Touloudou The layout is probably what you expected, but with extra padding after the last member. Unfortunately, there is no standard way to verify that this is actually happening. If you need bit-perfect control you should use `std::bitset` for bit flags or bitwise masks and operators on fixed width unsigned integers for more complicated applications. C++ doesn't have good features for bit-mapping types.

Comment: @Touloudou I don't understand. The layout is like you wanted it to be as I understand

Comment: What happens if you replace `unsigned int` with `usigned char`?

Comment: @Yunnosch He mentioned this. 2bytes size

Comment: It's hard to check because I can't get the address of bit field members. From what you told me, the basic answer is: I can't rely on bit fields for my application. I'll probably have to use bit shifts to get what I want.

Comment: @Thrasher I missed that (and still am blind....). But then what is the question? "I want 2byte size, which get when using char." So what? Ah, I now see that you asked the same....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [[class.bit]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.bit#1) [extract]:

> [...] Allocation of bit-fields within a class object is implementation-defined. Alignment of bit-fields is implementation-defined.

and, from [[defns.impl.defined]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/defns.impl.defined):

> #### implementation-defined behavior
>
> behavior, for a well-formed program construct and correct data, **that
> depends on the implementation** and **that each implementation documents**

Thus, for a portable implementation you cannot rely on any specific kind of behaviour for implementation-defined behaviour. If you are developing for a particular platform and compiler, however, you *could* rely on documented implementation-defined behaviour to a certain extent.